# Jquery script not executing on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am a bit new to this, but I can't figure out why my jquery script isn't executing. It is a function inside my main.js and I am calling it like this:

```
jQuery(function($){
    geoCode();
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/tZNw4/2/

I expect the alert to come up on page load but actually it doesn't do anything. Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ) `. [Learn how to **debug** JavaScript.](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/javascript-debugging-beginners).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a misstype error with the semicolon on your javascript:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZNw4/19/

```
function geoCode() {
  alert("test");
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be in document ready like

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    geoCode();
});
```

And see this [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/tZNw4/13/) that you gave us.You put extra closing brace ')' at the end

Comment: They're already using the shorthand syntax, document ready isn't the issue.

Comment: And also I mentioned the closing brace issue

Answer (score 1):

Remove last closing bracket in JavaScript window.

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is here in the function:

```
function geoCode() {
   alert("test");
}); //<------------------see here the closing `);`
```

make it like this:

```
function geoCode() {
   alert("test");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try document.ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    geoCode();
});
```

Edit: ah, they do the same (TIL).

Fixed it for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/tZNw4/18/

Comment: `$(function() {...});` is identical to doing `$(document).ready(function() {...});`, it's just shorthand.

Answer (score 0):

I'll think you should use the document ready event.

```
jQuery(document).ready( function() {
  geoCode();
});
```

Comment: They already are, they've just used the shorthand syntax for it.

Comment: Oh thanks...I thaught jQuery( function($) { .. } ); will be executed once when the parser reaches it. (So during the page rendering..).

Comment: Well, it will but the callback function will be exacuted when the DOM is ready.